# NoClassDefFoundError while handling asm dependency with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

When I tried to use gradle to build a program using asm package, I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
    at analysis.CCMetric.main(CCMetric.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

My gradle script is as follow:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'analysis.CCMetric'

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }    
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm-all:5.0.2'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'org.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:0.9.1'
    compile 'asm:asm:3.3.1'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'analysis.CCMetric'
    }
    baseName = 'CCMetric'
    version = '1.0.0'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

I used gradle build to build the project and I run the jar file with java -jar build/libs/CCMetric.jar and then I got the exception as above.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution from Gradle Forum. Now I'm pasting the answer from Muschko, B.

> You will also have to provide the external JARs you are depending on
>   when executing the Java command. Gradle does not hook into the Java
>   command magically and provide the external libraries. A good
>   alternatively you can look into is the Application plugin which does
>   something you are looking for out-of-the-box with the run task.